# Таймаут между BluetoothSocket.close и BluetoothSocket.connect в Android.

Tags: android, сокет, bluetooth

Соединяю свой планшет с bluetooth-модулем китайского происхождения (он работает, как мастер). При повороте экрана все потоки убиваются и создаются новые. Если после поворота экрана и перед строкой

```
socket.connect()
```

не делать задержки, то соединение не проходит. При задержке в 100 мс все соединяется.
Вопроса два:

1. Правильно ли я делаю, что убиваю существующее соединение (может есть какой-то способ его сохранить - вообще, потоки остаются живы после поворота экрана)? Сейчас я сохраняю с savedInstanceState адрес удаленного устройства и при повороте экрана заново создаю поток соединения и поток обработки соединения.
2. Если первый вопрос "да", то какую задержку лучше поставить. По-моему, 100 мс - это много (не хочется тыкать...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не правильно. Убивать соединение не нужно. Создайте поток, который будет принадлежать процессу, а не активити и пусть он себе работает, отсылая уведомления. А если ещё более по правильному  - сделайте сервис:)

Comment: Про поток, принадлежащий процессу можно подробнее?
Сервис, ИМХО, из пушки по воробьям в моем случае...

Comment: Наиболее простой способ - создайте статическое поле в своем активити. Но главное в этот поток не тянуть визуальные элементы, а то будет утечка ресурсов.

Comment: Не, все визуальное в активити и фрагментах. У меня все так и делается... Видимо, надо пересматривать работу кнопок, посылающих управляющие сигналы.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо вам :) Работает. Плюсик вам

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно зачем связывать потоки с поворотом экрана. Поворот экрана должен влиять только на отрисовку элементов, но никак не на логику проги. Я думаю вы тут что-то сильно намудрили с архитектурой приложения. Вынесите работу с bluetooth в отдельный класс/поток и пусть он там спокойно работает. По `Activity.onCreate()` вам надо отобразить текущее состояние коннекта и ход его работы, а привязывать запуск коннекта к открытию/закрытию `Activity` как то не очень разумно.

Лучше уж "посадить" запуск потока к `Application.onCreate()` - тогда он будет работать всегда вне зависимости от открытия/закрытия `Activity`

Comment: Архитектура повторяет ту, что в примере BluetoothChat. Все так, как вы написали. Значит, видимо, надо работать с кнопками, которые посылают управляющие сигналы